# Processor API toplology number of sink targets limit

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Using kafka processor API (not DSL) , below is the topology description:

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;

Topology topology = new Topology();
topology.addSource("mySource", "source_topic_name");
topology.addProcessor("StreamProcessor",()->new StreamProcessor(), "mySource");
topology.addSink("sink1","TargetTopic1","StreamProcessor");
topology.addSink("sink2","TargetTopic2","StreamProcessor");
```

What is the maximum limit for the number of sinks (sink1,sink2....sinkn) which can be added to the topology?

Comment: There is no limit (maybe `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as arrays are limited to this size in Java).

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax. Thanks for confirming sir.